# C# .NET interoperabillity with managed Python (CPython) -> any problems?

Tags: c#, .net, python, interop, ironpython

I am working on a design of an application. The Core should be written in C# but i also want to use some already finished CPython modules (un-managed).

So I am interested in the interoperability (Call CPython method from C# and Call C# from CPython). And if there are problems, because C# runs within the .NET runtime (managed) and CPython directly un-managed.

I already investigated this issue with Google and came out to these solutions:

- Use IronPython via DLR + "CPython extension" + maybe "IronClad" and call from IronPython the CPython modules and vice versa -> are these modules executed managed or unmanaged ? Are There any problems if i want to use C# classes and methods from CPython ?
- Use "Python for .NET" -> the same question as above.

What do you think, which way would be better ? or do you have another solution ?

And the last but maybe most important question, did I understand the above mentioned points right, or do I mess up ?

Many thanks in advance !!

Comment: In what sense are your modules `CPython` (as opposed to just plain Python)? I ask because there aren't many implementation-dependent features, though there definitely are some. It would be much simpler just to use IronPython, which runs on .NET and interacts happily with C# using the DLR.

Comment: Thank you for your reply katrielalex, I dont want to rewrite the CPython modules because they are many. I also think that IronPython would be better but desperatly all the modules are written in CPython. One more question:  I am not familiar with Python at all, but if CPython is based on C, are the modules after compiling just native DLL's and can I treat them from C# just as DLL's (via dllimport ?).

Comment: No, you don't understand. CPython is an _implementation_ of the Python language which happens to be written in C. (Just like, say, the C# compiler is written in C++.) Although it's possible to write Python code that depends on the specific implementation, in general any Python works anywhere.

Comment: Also, Python isn't compiled. (Well, not really.) It's _interpreted_: there's a program called the interpreter which just takes a source file and executes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand Python. It's an interpreted<sup>1</sup> language. You just provide the text source files and the interpreter will execute them.

There is a difference between the *language* Python and the *implementations* CPython, IronPython, Jython, PyPy, what have you. Each of them attempts to implement the language Python as accurately as possible, while also adding implementation-specific functionality. This is just like how, say, the C# compiler was written in C++.

For example, any (pure) Python file can be executed by the IronPython interpreter. But if you know that you're going to use IronPython, you can use the special IronPython features that let you into the .NET library.

Now, most Python doesn't use any of the implementation-specific functionality, so it doesn't matter what you use to run it. Some Python does, though.

<sup>1</sup>Well, it's compiled into .pyc files... but then "compile" isn't really a well-defined term anyway.

---

Why does this matter to you? Well, you have a bunch of Python source code that you want to use with the .NET framework. If that code doesn't use any of the CPython-specific features -- such as using C extension modules -- then you can just run it in IronPython.

Comment: Thank you for your Information. Yes, you are right, CPython is interpreted. But do you have experience with the CPython extension for IronPython ---> http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/cpython_extensions.shtml ?

Comment: @user1341210: I do not. But you still haven't answered my question: are you sure you need that module? It's for running _CPython_ extensions in IronPython, and you haven't said in what way your modules are specific to the C implementation of Python.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't answer the question yet because I did not received the modules yet. I think the first point for me would be to analyse these modules in what way they are specific C implemented when i received them. But thank you for your effort !

Comment: I think the first thing to do would be to run them in IronPython and see if they work! Good luck =)

Comment: Hello katrielalex, here is my update: I finally convinced the cpython developers to switch to C# because it is more usefull for our purpose. But many thanks for the answers !

Answer (score 1):

Expose your Python code via COM and call that from C#. Used this avenue (both ways) many times.